# NPE in setUp() method for a ProviderTestCase subclass

Tags: java, android, testing, android-contentprovider

I currently have the following `setUp()` method in my `ProviderTestCase2`. It throws an NPE deep inside the Android API after the call to `newResolverWithContentProviderFromSql()`. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

```
public void setUp() throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    this.resolver = newResolverWithContentProviderFromSql(this.getMockContext(),
            "test.", BaseballCardProvider.class,
            BaseballCardContract.AUTHORITY,
            BaseballCardSQLHelper.DATABASE_NAME,
            BaseballCardSQLHelper.SCHEMA_VERSION, CREATE_TABLE
                    + INSERT_DATA);
}
```

Here's the stack trace for reference:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException  
at android.test.RenamingDelegatingContext.openOrCreateDatabase(RenamingDelegatingContext.java:146)  
at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:215)  
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.createDbFromSqlStatements(DatabaseUtils.java:1315)  
at android.test.ProviderTestCase2.newResolverWithContentProviderFromSql(ProviderTestCase2.java:219)  
at bbct.android.common.provider.test.BaseballCardProviderTest.setUp(BaseballCardProviderTest.java:44)  
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)  
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)  
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)  
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1584)
```

Comment: Are you overriding `setUp()` in `ProviderTestCase2`? You should call up to `super` if that is the case.

Comment: @A--C /facepalm thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have overriden `setUp()` but not called up to `super.setUp()`, the TestCase isn't complete because like the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ProviderTestCase2.html) says:

> This framework is set up automatically by the base class' setUp()
>   method. If you override this method, you must call the super method as
>   the first statement in your override.